# CS 0102: The type ' ' already contains a definition for ' '

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have the titled error CS 0302 stating that "The type 'EditMemberPage' already contains a definition for 'takePhoto with my code associated with line 30. I am trying to use media plugin to take pictures with an iPhone emulator. Here is the code:

```
using Relate.Model;
using Plugin.Media;
using Plugin.Media.Abstractions;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;


namespace Relate.Views
{
    public partial class EditMemberPage : ContentPage
    {

        public EditMemberPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            takePhoto.Clicked += async (sender, args) =>
            {

                if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || 
        !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
                {
                    DisplayAlert("No Camera", ":( No camera avaialble.", "OK");
                    return;
                }

                var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new 
        Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
                {
                    Directory = "Test",
                    SaveToAlbum = true,
                    CompressionQuality = 75,
                    CustomPhotoSize = 50,
                    PhotoSize = PhotoSize.MaxWidthHeight,
                    MaxWidthHeight = 2000,
                    DefaultCamera = CameraDevice.Front
                    });

                if (file == null)
                    return;

                DisplayAlert("File Location", file.Path, "OK");

                image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
                  {
                  var stream = file.GetStream();
                  file.Dispose();
                  return stream;
              });
            };
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please mark the relevant line.  Note that this is a partial class, which means the implementation is in more than one source file.  The error may be a different file than the one you have shown here.

Comment: have you searched your entire solution for "takePhoto"?

Comment: The code example doesn't even contain the declaration for `takePhoto`. Would probably help us to understand the problem if it did.

Comment: Thank you @DiegoRafaelSouza, I had more than one takePhoto button that is why this was occurring.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is more to EditMemberPage.cs than you're showing us, look in EditMemberPage.xaml. You probably have two elements with x:Name="takePhoto".

An element with an x:Name creates a member in that class whose name is the value of the x:Name. So you can't have more than one element with the same x:Name, nor can you have a member declared in C# with the same name as an element's x:Name.

Comment: Thank @DavidS, I had more than one takePhoto button that is why this was occurring.